# Fedora environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, root, fedora

I'm very new to this so apologies if it doesn't make sense. I can't log into my computer (fedora 27) because I think I've incorrectly assigned an environmental variable called PATH.

I tried to set a path for an environmental variable by using

```
vi ~/.bashrc
PATH=usr/local/bin
```

once I exited vi the terminal would keep popping up with the question 'do you want to install sed? N/y'

I exited the terminal and started a new one but the same problem occurred.
I thought if I restarted my machine it may resolve itself but now I can't log back onto my personal user account. I input my password and it accepts it, starts to load the homepage but then asks for my password again. I can't think of what I did apart from set the local environment variable PATH.

I can log onto the root user so my question is does anyone know how to change the local environmental variable on my personal account while being logged onto the root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vi /home/user/.bashrc
```

Something like that?

Change the PATH Variable to something like this:

> PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin

Comment: Two notes: First `usr/local/bin` without a leading `/` is unusual and _probably_ not what you want. Second, `/usr/local/bin` is _already_ in the default path.